# CSS dots appearing below menu

Tags: html, css

Alright so the problem is quite simple, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

After I created this code, there are like small dots appearing bellow the menu.

Check the picture to understand it more.

[image: Purple link dots]

**Code**

```css
#MenuID li {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 146, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 220;
  top: -48;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#MenuID li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
#MenuID li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="MenuID">
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </li>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Forum</li>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Website</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You didn't close your anchors properly

Comment: besides the un-closed anchors (*`a` tags*) which is the real problem you also have no units on the `top` and `left` properties. You should add `px` most likely next to them.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the `</a>` before the `</li>` and use `min-width` in `li`, plus you are missing units in `left` and `top`

```css
#MenuID li {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 146, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 220px;
 /* top: -48px; commented so you can see demo*/
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#MenuID li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
#MenuID li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="MenuID">
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Home</a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Forum</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Website</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never closing your `<a>`'s in your HTML:

```
<ul id="MenuID">
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a></li>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Forum</a></li>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Website</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, I failed... Thanks mate